# DFS on evolving graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I think I am fairly certain that the DFS algorithm for the problem should not be any different from a normal DFS, but just wanted to get some feedback from other. Here is my problem:

I would like to perform DFS on a graphs for which I do not know all the nodes. When I start the search all I know is just the start node. Based on the start node's properties, I can determine it's set of child nodes. The children of the nodes that have just been discovered can be further discovered as above.

I am planning to use an algorithm similar to a normal DFS (where the Graph is known before hand) except that every time I reach a node, I now need to discover it's child nodes.

Is this a reasonable approach? I am I missing something?

Comment: It will work, but keep in mind that it will be explore all nodes reachable from one of the child nodes before continuing with the next child node. For infinite graphs this might not be what you want. In that case you can use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [iterative deepening DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) instead

Comment: It will work fine. Nothing about the DFS algorithm assumes any knowledge about the graph other than the current node and its immediate neighbors.

Comment: What do you want to do by traversing the graph using DFS? If you want a list of the vertices in the graph, then applying a normal dfs will work as explained in the answers. While if you want to discover all the edges, then the dfs algorithms explained below wont work. This is because once you have completed dfs from 2 vertices and a new edge is added between those two, then you wont discover this new edge.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a perfectly reasonable approach.

However, without knowing the exact details of what you're trying to do, it's next-to-impossible to say for sure whether it will work or be the best approach.

If this is a large (possibly infinite) graph (or it contains cycles and there are too many nodes to keep track of all of them as you do the DFS to prevent getting stuck in a cycle) and you're looking for some node not too deep in the graph, either [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS with iterative deepening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search_with_iterative_deepening) might be a better idea.

Comment: A simplified version of the problem I am trying to solve, is similar to creating software call-graphs. For example, I would like to know the call graph which is 10 level deep for a particular API. I can start with this API and as I discover the callers of this API, I add them to the list of children of this node and proceed as described above.

Answer (score 0):

DFS stands for Depth First Search. and by "Search" it means it does not know what is ahead of it. So DFS on a known graph is no different from DFS on a graph where you get to know the child just at the time you reach the parent.